# combining COUNTA statements in a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to sum the instances of a character in a column of a google spreadsheet.  The complication is that the sum is weighted by case.  So for a column containing [X,X,x,X], I would want 3.5.  What I have so far is a formula resembling the following:

```
=0.5*COUNTA(FILTER(H3:H, FIND("x", H3:H)))+COUNTA(FILTER(H3:H, FIND("X", H3:H)))
```

which does not work.  It seems to give me 1.5 * the number of capital 'X' there are in the row.

However,

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(H3:H, FIND("x", H3:H)))
=COUNTA(FILTER(H3:H, FIND("X", H3:H)))
```

each work on their own, except in the case where there are no entries of the correct-cased 'x', in which case they return 1 (and not 0).

What is the issue with using a compound statement of this form?  And secondarily, why does a null query result return 1?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: After some testing, it looks like spreadsheets is having problems with combining two lists of the same character, but with different cases. The list of lower case characters become capitalized. It might only be applying when using `FILTER`. As for your null query, it's just how `COUNTA` is. Use `=IFERROR(COUNTA(FORMULA), 0)` to have it properly return 0.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andy explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094397/combining-counta-statements-in-a-single-cell#comment48556569_24094397) there are certain problems when using FIND as argument of FILTER.

Instead of using FIND use [CODE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094122?hl=en) and compare the results with 120 for x and 88 for X, by the other hand instead of COUNTA and FILTER use just [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)

If the column A has the the following values

```
X  
X  
x  
X
```

then the formula

```
=ArrayFormula(0.5*COUNTIF(code($A$1:A),"=120")+COUNTIF(code($A$1:A),"=88"))
```

will return 3.5